# Como iterar sobre um arquivo JSON para aparecer na listagem do Auto Complete?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jquery-ui

Estou fazendo um autocomplete, via `AJAX`, que entra no Web service, "busca no Banco" e me retorna uma String no formato `JSON`.

Tenho que transformar o `JSON` abaixo em um lista para iterar sobre ela.

No `data.d` obtenho a seguinte String:

```
"[{"IDPais":1,"Pais1":"Brasil","IDIdioma":1}]"
```

Ao ler o arquivo `JSON` com a função `$.map` dá erro no console.

Meu código:

```
$(function() {
    $("#<%=txtPais.ClientID%>").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '<%=ResolveUrl("../ws/AutoComplete.asmx/GetListaPais")%>',
                data: "{ 'prefixText': '" + request.term + "','contextKey': '" + $("#<%=rblIdiomas.ClientID%> input:checked").val() + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function(item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.Pais1,
                            val: item.IDPais
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function(response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function(response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 1
    });
});
```

Comment: Faz um alert na função success para ver o resultado.

Comment: Ele deve ta lendo uma String, e não um JSON, então tenta fazer isso:

`var jsonObj = JSON.parse(data.d);
$.map(jsonObj, function (item) {.......`

Comment: @Rogerio Alencar Filho poste seu comentario como resposta, para que eu possa marcalo como correto. Outra forma de fazer em vez de usar Json.parse(data.d) seria var dados = eval(data.d)

Comment: @RogerioAlencarFilho poste sua resposta aqui por favor, pra mim marca-lá como correta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse(data.d)` para transformar seu JSON em uma lista de objetos e interar sobre ela com a função `$.map`. O `sucess` do ajax deveria ficar assim:

```
success: function (data) {
    var dados = JSON.parse(data.d);
    response($.map(dados, function (item) {
        return {
            label: item.Pais1,
            val: item.IDPais
        }
    }));
}
```

Respondi a pergunta pois o amigo @RogerioAlencarFilho deixou ela nos comentários e achei interessante deixá-la aqui.